# Disabling 'Populate Custom Fields When Uploading Files' feature

Tags: lightning, files, content, document

I'm using lightning:fileUpload component to load files, and I came accross a new, unnecessary feature. Recently when adding file, the button on popup window displaying uploading status changed from 'done' to 'next', and instead of creating the file it opens another window where I can populate some fields. Is there a way to disable that second window? I don't want to populate anything, I just want my file uploaded.

Answer (score 0):

This is a new feature in Winter 19'
http://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter19/release-notes/rn_networks_files_edit_detail_page.htm?edition=&impact=