# How can I allow the user to Populate Custom Fields When Uploading Files?

Tags: lightning, community, files

### Update: I managed to get the dialog to display but the implementation feels like a bug workaround. See update below.

How can I get this **Add File Details** dialog to display allowing the user to add file details when uploading a file?

https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter19/release-notes/rn_networks_files_custom_fields.htm

[image]

It doesn't work for me in any of the locations the documentation says it will. The only place I haven't tried it yet is in a custom component that includes `lightning:fileUpload` but it says it should work in Files home or the standard related list, which it just doesn't.

I've tested in a community with one custom field on Content Document, with and without a validation rule, with and without a required field, using the Combined Attachments related list, as well as the Files related list and none of them produce a UI similar to what is shown in the documentation.

Upon successful upload, it allows me to dismiss the modal. Upon unsuccessful upload (such as violating a required field check) I am presented with a message for "can't upload file" and the dismiss button of the modal changes to "Got It". At no point does it change to "Next" as I've seen [described in other questions](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/234618/disabling-populate-custom-fields-when-uploading-files-feature) or "Save" as in the screenshot from the documentation.

Is there a toggle to allow this UI to be shown to a user?

---

### Update:

I managed to get the dialog for **Add File Details** to appear (in LEX and Community interfaces) by adding a required field on the object as well as adding a `Record Type` to the `Content Version` object. Without both a required field and a RT, the user is not prompted to add details. They instead see the error message `Can't upload <filename>.` as seen here:

[image]

Once a `Record Type` is added to the `Content Version` object, the **Add File Details** dialog is presented after the file is uploaded, as seen here:

**Step 1**

[image]

**Step 2**

[image]

1. Is this working as designed?
2. What if I don't want to `Record Type` the `Content Version` object? I only need the user to populate a couple of custom fields.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks @Mark Pond for this great description. I too found the only way to do this is to make the field Required. This was a problem for me as I only wanted the field to be displayed only for some users. Unfortunately fields on the ContentVersion do not allow for profile-level Read-Edit permissions.

The solution was to add a Default Field Value logic.

I made the field required and then using the Default Field value I set it to NA for the profiles that should not see this field and left the default blank for profiles that should see and populate the fields.

As a result the field displayed on the Next screen for those that should see it and Done for those that did not need to see the field on file upload.

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=fields_useful_default_field_values.htm&type=5